# Deserialize raw JSON and convert to custom C# Object

Tags: c#, json, pubnub

I have the following raw JSON string:

```
[\"Hello World!\",\"94952923696694934\",\"MyChannel\"]
```

I have tried the following without luck:

My custom object class:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string msg { get; set; }
   public string id { get; set; }
   public string chn { get; set; }
}
```

JSON string:

```
string str = "[\"Hello World!\",\"94952923696694934\",\"MyChannel\"]";
```

1st attempt at deserilization using *System.Web.Script.Serialization*:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
MyObject obj1 = serializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(str);
```

2nd attempt at deserilization using *Newtonsoft.Json*:

```
MyObject obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(str);
```

Both attempts fail. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a JSON array of strings, not an object with property names.

So the best you can do here is to deserialize the array:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<string>>(str);
```

...then use the resulting sequence `strings` as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

With PubNub, you can just pass in the native String, Dictionary, or Array, and we'll JSON encode it for you on the publish side, and auto JSON decode for you on the subscriber side.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your 'custom object' isn't equivalent to the json representation. The json you're deserializing is just a `string[]` in C# (you can also use `List<string>` or other IEums).

So in code you're looking for;

```
string[] theJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(str);
```

`MyObject` would be used for the following json;

```
{
     "msg":"Hello World!",
     "id":"94952923696694934",
     "chn":"MyChannel"
}
```